# Introductory Java Student assigning an existing variable to another

Tags: java

My apologies if this seems like a simple question, I am a new Computer Science student and this question has me stumped.

Suppose a Car variable billsCar exists and already refers to a Car object.
Write a statement that assigns billsCar's unused capacity to the double variable amtLeft.

Below is the source code:

```
  public class Car{
 // the Car attributes
 String make; // manufacturer
 double fuelCapacity;
 double fuelAmount;

 // the Car constructor

  public Car(String what, double cap, double amt){
  make = what;
  fuelCapacity = cap;
  fuelAmount = amt;
 }
 // the Car methods
  public String getMake(){
  return make;
 }
  public double getCapacity(){
  return fuelCapacity;
 }
  public double getFuel(){
  return fuelAmount;
}
  public void setFuel(double amt){
    fuelAmount = amt;
 }
    public double unusedCap(){
    return (fuelCapacity - fuelAmount);
 }
   }
```

The answer block begins with double amtLeft = ;
What would be the proper way of assigning billsCar unused capacity (a varible I do not know) to the double variable amtLeft?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, can you clarify?

Comment: What would the java statement be that would assign billsCars unused capacity to the double variable amtLeft? Pretty much how would I write it so that if I was to print amtLeft it would print billsCars unused capacity?

Comment: You mean `double amtLeft = billsCar.unusedCap();`?

Answer (score 0):

Change unusedCap() to this?

```
public double unusedCap() {
            double fuelLeft=(fuelCapacity - fuelAmount);
            return fuelLeft;
}
```

Comment: The way the question is formatted in the program we use for class, I cannot edit the source code. So pretty much it shows me the source code, and then gives me a response box that starts with "double amtLeft = ;" so I need to answer given that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like

```
Car billsCar = new Car ("Ford", 40.0, 20.0); // half full

System.out.println ("The remaining capacity is " + billsCar.unusedCap ());
```

// now because we are using doubles (when are not stored as exact value) there may be some strange rounding problems, so try

```
System.out.format("The remaining capacity is %.2f%n",  billsCar.unusedCap ());
```